# Can you list receiving addresses in bitcoin-cli?

Tags: bitcoin-cli

In bitcoin-qt, there are interfaces for seeing "receiving addresses" which have been generated in the past. I don't see any way to do that in bitcoin-cli.

Comment: `$ bitcoin-cli listreceivedbyaddress | grep address` ?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can do it.

```
bitcoin-cli listreceivedbyaddress 1 true
```

I had to read the argument documentation. Thanks Sven Williamson.