# Can we get any default address before running getnewaddress?

Tags: bitcoind, client

I am trying to develop some application using bitcoin (currently only in the regtest mode). 
I am aware that one can create a new address using

`bitcoin-cli -regtest getnewaddress`

RPC call, but I want to know whether bitcoind pre-generates a bitcoin wallet address when we install and run

`bitcoind -regtest -daemon`

fresh. If yes, how can I know this address?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you list receiving addresses in bitcoin-cli?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/50314/can-you-list-receiving-addresses-in-bitcoin-cli)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

The wallet actually always pregenerates keys (not addresses) and puts them in the keypool. A keys is fetched from the keypool and converted to an address only when an address is explicitly requested (via `getnewaddress` or from the GUI). An address is not pre-fetched by default.

Comment: Thank you Andrew. Where can I find these pre-generated keys?

Comment: You can't without using `getnewaddress`. They are not shown to users as keys by themselves are not particularly useful.